# How do i align the Angular materials checkboxes vertically with different text sizes inside div and keep them in middle of div

Tags: css, angular, sass, flexbox, angular-material

Here is the stackbliz show the issue: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-addm8z-rng1eb?file=app/checkbox-overview-example.css

[Image of the Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EjM2.png)

[Expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fct3U.png)

Comment: Just remove the text-align:center; css rule?

Comment: My use case is to keep them in center and align them as mentioned, Updated stackbliz, with my use case with @Borad Akash suggestion, but facing scroll issue as you see in stackbliz

Comment: As you've set height and overflow, that'll show the scroll, that's the behavior of css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the width to `cb-wrapper`.

i.e

```
    .cb-wrapper
    {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    }
```

Comment: Tried with with the scenario i have , facing the issue with scroll bar coming to middle of screen next to content instead of left most like normal